# $_SESSION['var'] does not save the variable until the second login

Tags: php, session

I try to login to my site but the $_SESSION[] variable is not saving the data. I can't login until I try a second time. It only happens when I login for the first time in any computer. After that When I login again in the same computer it only takes one try. Erasing the cookies makes have to login twice again.
I check if the variable exists in page.php and if it does not it redirects me to index.php

code in page.php to check if session login variable is empty

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
session_start();
ob_start();


if(empty($_SESSION['login'])){
    echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=index.php">';
}
```

this is the code that I have (index.php):

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
include("conec.php");

$message="";


    if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
        //echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=page.php">';
    }

    $message="";
    if(isset($_POST['send'])) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT login FROM user WHERE login='" . $_POST["login"] . "' and password = '". $_POST["password"]."'");
        $row  = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        if(is_array($row)) {
            $_SESSION['login'] = $row[login];
            echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=page.php">';
        } else {
            $message = "Invalid user or password!";
        }

    }

        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="login">Login:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" name="login">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10"> 
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="send" id="send" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Send</button><br />
        </form>
```

I have also tried

```
header("Location: page.php");
header("Location: http://www.page.php");
echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.page.php">';
```

The only one that has been able to redirect me to other pages has been when I use either

```
echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.page.php">';
```

or

```
echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=page.php">';
```

Comment: have you start session on  `page.php`

Comment: I updated the code for page.php, yes I do start session in it

Comment: add `session_start();` at top of the file. and try

Comment: this line will be error $_SESSION['login'] = $row[login]; try by enclose " $row["login"];

Comment: @urfusion, I set session_start(); at the top and still same problem.

Comment: @DavidJawphan, changed $_SESSION['login'] = $row['login']; still same problem

Comment: you should remove `ob_start();`.. It makes no sense here.. also.. I don't see where page.php is used.. it's not included in index.. how do you use it?

Comment: Your way to verify to login is totally wrong.. You should use the form action attribute to submit the form to a `login.php` file.. In that login.php file you should check the credentials in the db and set the session variables..

Comment: @MateiMihai index.php redirects to page.php after login atempt and if the variable does not exist it redirects back to index.php

Comment: You should read more about authenticating systems.. Is not that simple to be implemented.. Also.. you are using `mysql_` functions which are deprecated, you are not preventing SQL injection, you are using plain passwords (you should encrypt the password when storing it), and other mistakes.. read more about this topic and try refactoring the code

Comment: Doing this worked! I guess I was starting a session over a session
"Your way to verify to login is totally wrong.. You should use the form action attribute to submit the form to a login.php file.. In that login.php file you should check the credentials in the db and set the session variables.." – @MateiMihai

Comment: You don't need `ob_start()` I believe you can avoid this in your code, drop the `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');` , replace your `meta`-tags with `header("Location: page.php");die();`, close `php`-tag to separate php-code and html-code.